# always on top child window in multiple child windows in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, childwindow

I have several child windows and i want one of the these child windows always on top of all other opened child windows. i want when i do close or open other child windows, this child window always on top of all current child windows.
child window not have a z-index property?

please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not a lot of work experience with child windows, but have some idea...). If child window is a part of to inherited tree of FrameworkElement then you can try call "Focus" method for displaying it on the top.

Comment: thanks Vitaliy. in actually my problem was this: i have many child windows and one child window who that is a progress bar for waiting WCF services. i want when the system is busy for wcf services, any one of the these child windows not allowed work with system until the request of service ending. finally for solve this problem, i disable all child windows when progress bar child window is showing and after request is complete, enable all those